# How to get a selected Textblock items of a combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf

How to get a selected Textblock items of a combobox in WPF ?

Here is my code

```
 <ComboBox Width="180" Name="comboBox">
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Background="Red"></Label>
                        <TextBlock Width="150">Apple</TextBlock>
                        <Label ></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, following code is one of possible approaches but be cautious this type of code may not cover all possible scenarios, for example if there is a change in layout templates etc.:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content as StackPanel;
    TextBlock tbkValue = null;
    if (item != null)
    {
       tbkValue = (item as StackPanel).Children.Cast<UIElement>().ToList().Where(it => it.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock)).Cast<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    if(tbkValue != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(tbkValue.Text);
    }
}
```

Instead I recommend WPF's powerful data binding approach may be using MVVM, whenever there is a possibility, which not only ease most of the complexity of to and fro data updates but also much cleaner, maintainable and of course unit testable code as well.

Hope this provide you some idea.